# How can I recursively pass Quotes in Scala 3 macros?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-3

I’m building a macro-based json serializer (Scala 3).  I’m having trouble with recursion inside the macros—esp quotes.

I have a reflection library that generates an RType holding all the needed reflection bits.
At a high level I want to switch on the RType and based on what the type of the thing is, generate a function
to serialize it.  Like this macro for String:

```scala
  inline def toJson[T](t: T): String = ${ toJsonImpl[T]('t, '{RType.of[T]}) }

  def toJsonImpl[T:Type](t: Expr[T], r: Expr[RType])(using quotes:Quotes): Expr[String] = {
    import quotes.reflect.* 

    // Based on a given type, produce a fn that accepts some value and a StringBuilder and returns the 
    // StringBuffer after appending the rendered Json string for that value
    def renderJsonFn(rt: RType): Expr[(Any,StringBuilder) => StringBuilder] = 
      rt match {
        // Sample for a simple string => json rendering
        case PrimitiveType.Scala_String => 
          '{(a:Any, sb:StringBuilder) => 
            sb.append('"')
            sb.append(a.toString)
            sb.append('"')
          }
 
      //… more RTypes here
```

When done, I just call the generated chain of functions, passing in a StringBuffer, and they all append whatever
Is needed to serialize the thing.

Ok… so my question.  I hit a snag with Class types, specifically because they can be nested.  I need to be able
To call renderJsonFn() recursively, and I get an error with Quotes.  Here’s the related piece of rt match{} for Class:

```scala
        case c: ClassInfo =>
          val rtExp = Expr(rt)
          val fieldFns = Expr.ofList(c.fields.toList.map(f => renderJsonFn(f.fieldType))) // get render fn’s for each class field

          '{(a:Any, sb:StringBuilder) => 
            sb.append('{')

            val classInfo = $rtExp.asInstanceOf[ClassInfo]
            val thing = Expr(a)//  <- error here trying to wrap the object value ‘a’ in an Expression:
              // access to parameter quotes from wrong staging level:
              //   - the definition is at level 0,
              //   - but the access is at level 1.
              
            // resolve() here calls Select.unique(thing, "foom").asExpr
            val fieldValues = classInfo.fields.map{ _.asInstanceOf[ScalaFieldInfo].resolve(thing) }.toList

            val zipped = ${fieldFns}.zip(fieldValues)
            zipped.map{ case (fn,v) =>
              fn(a,sb)
            }
            sb.setCharAt(sb.length()-1,'}')
          }
```

I’ve tried some goofy ways of passing quotes into renderJsonFn() but it didn’t help—I was likely doing it wrong.  How can I get access to quotes/q a the right level here, and make sure it works recursively, so I can descend into a hierarchy of classes?

Comment: I feel that I miss too much context here. `Quotes` can be passed recursively: one method working on `Expr`s and `Type`s can call another (like any other method). However, if you want to handle recursive data structures this way (take some type, get its fields/subtypes, pattern match on them, for each get type, get its fields/subtypes...), you can easily create an infinite recursion in macro - you'd have to manually prevent that, and e.g. generate a type class instance which is recursive but in runtime. Out of curiosity, is it like a learning exercise or do you want to use it on production?